# The Metric Tensor Of A Cartesian Product

Tags: differential-geometry, physics

Hello I'm a physics student, not a math student, who is trying to understand how to write down the metric of a manifold which is constructed via a cartesian product of two other manifolds I know the metrics for. For example S^1 X S^1 is a Torus and I know the metric for a Circle, and I even know the metric for a Torus, but I do not know how to derive the metric for a Torus from the Cartesian product of two circles. In the end I want to construct the metric for the S^1 X S^2. Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Would you add the metrics you know to the question?

Comment: Well the metric of the surface of a circle is simply ds^2= r^2 * dtheta^2 for a Torus I can compute the metric via in the Induced Metric in R^3 and that metric is (r_2+(r_1)*Cos(theta_1))^2*dtheta_2 +(r_1)^2*dtheta_1 where theta 1 and theta 2 go from 0 to 2*Pi

Comment: Oh and the Metric of the sphere is r^2*dtheta^2 +r^2*Sin(theta)^2*dphi^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two Riemannian Manifolds $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ then we define their product metric at the point $(p,q)\in M\times N$ as
$$g \oplus h: (T_pM\times T_qN) \times (T_pM\times T_qN) \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
$$(g\oplus h)_{(p,q)}((v,w),(\hat v,\hat w)):=g_p(v,\hat v)+h_q(w,\hat w)$$